# (Java) How to find the occurrence of a specific element from a List of objects ? (Not List of elements)

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of students and their respective grades in different subjects.
I want to find out how many of them got at least 3 'F'.

Let me describe what I have.

I have a list of students that looks like this (more or less):

```
List<Student> studentsList= {Alpha, Beta, Gamma...};
```

The Student class:

```
public class Student {
    private int studentId;
    private String studentName;
    private List<Grade> gradesList;

    public Student(int studentId, String studentName) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.studentName = studentName;
        gradesList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public int getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }

    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" + "studentId=" + studentId + ", studentName=" + studentName + '}';
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(studentName);
    }

    public List<Grade> getGradesList() {
        return gradesList;
    }
}
```

The Grade class:

```
public class Grade {
    private Course course;
    private int semesterId;
    private String grade;

    public Grade() {
    }

    public Grade(Course course, int semesterId, String grade) {
        this.course = course;
        this.semesterId = semesterId;
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    public Course getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public int getSemesterId() {
        return semesterId;
    }

    public String getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Grade{" + "course=" + course + ", semesterId=" + semesterId + ", grade=" + grade + '}';
    }
}
```

I believe I can get what I want by searching through each and every gradeList using the studentsList.

But I want to do it using stream() and lambda expressions. But can't figure out how?

This is how I can figure out how many students has a name longer than 15 digits and have a ID greater than 14900:

```
 List<Student> filteredList = studentsList.stream()
                .filter(s -> s.getStudentName().length() > 15)
                .filter(s -> s.getStudentId() > 14900)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        filteredList.forEach(System.out::println);

        long count = filteredList.stream().count();
        System.out.println(count + " entries");
```

P.S. If the question is missing some content please tell me what. I will try to provide everythin I can.

TIA.

Clarification:

I know how to count the number of elements from a List that matches a predicate. But when each of that List contains an object and I have to find out the value of a certain property of that object , I could find anything helpful anywhere.

EDIT:

This is [what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/no2QH.png) if I try to do it as my normal sense says:

EDIT 2:

Managed to do it, though not a nested stream(), but using an enhanced for loop and then a stream() inside of it.

```
System.out.println("Printing failed student list.");
        List<Grade> gradeList;

        int failCount = 0;
        for (Student student : studentsList) {
            gradeList = student.getGradesList().stream()
                    .filter(g -> g.getGrade().equals("F"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            long count = gradeList.stream().count();
            if (count > 2) {
                ++failCount;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Total: " + failCount + " entries.");
```

Still trying to figure out how to do it with using only stream().

Comment: I'm confused. You say _elements from a List that matches a predicate_. What's the difference between that and _find out the value of a certain property of that object_?

Comment: If it's a list of strings (suppose) it's simple to match e predicate.

But when it's a list of Objects and what I have to match if the value of eachObject.getGrade().equals("F") , I cannot find any way to do that.
I was thinking about predicate inside a predicate.. but my head hurts even thinking sometime about that :( 

I hope I managed to describe.

Comment: It's exactly the same whether the list contains strings or students. If you have to check that their grade is `F`, then do exactly what you suggested as the `Predicate`, `s.getGrade().equals("F") `.

Comment: I have added an EDIT at the last, basically the error I'm having with implementing what you said.

Comment: So, yes, you're going to have to nest there. `s -> s.getGradeList().stream().filter(..).count() > 2`.

Comment: Thanks! That might drive me towards my goal ! 
And I will post updates if I'm able to solve the problem. 
Thanks again!

Comment: You can optimize it a little using `s->s.getGradeList().stream().filter(…).limit(3).count()>2`, as the stream doesn’t need to count more than three here.